# mostrar en todo el ancho dentro de Reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

como ocupo ***Ancho de Toda la pagina*** de todo mi reportviewer que cuendo ejecupo por defecto me sale ***toda la pagina***

estoy trabajando en windows form

**me muestra asi por defecto:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**quiero que salga por defecto de esta manera**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esto te puede ayudar

```
 reportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;
```